# Call YUI3 script before onSubmit() of Button on Wicket Framework

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, wicket, yui, onsubmit

My requirement is on Click of "Submit" button -

1. loop through "< li >" elements on HTML page, get the objectURL from each
   "< li >" element, load the image on to Canvas and get dataURL from
   it. Store these dataURLs inside hidden field on HTML page.
2. Then retrieve the dataURLs from Hidden fields, convert them to byte
   array and proceed with further processing.

I targeted to achieve below way...

1.Using YUI3 java script (submitBehavior_js.js) to achieve the first part. Used ("click" event)

```
submitButton.add(new submitBehavior_js('click',parameters));
```

2.Overriding onSubmit() method of "Submit" button to achieve second part.

```
onSubmit(target,form)
{
String[] imgArray = null;
imgdata = hiddenImageData.getValue();
imgArray = imgData.split(',');
.........
}
```

I have gone through several threads and with my practical experience, onSubmit() java code is invoked before submitBehavior_js.js and so, the hidden fields didn't have any image data.

So, I tried to invoke the java script using "mouseup" event instead of "click". This was working perfectly fine and java script is running before the onSubmit() on wicket controller.

However, my code is adaptive web and it should work across browsers on mobile platforms. Evidently "mouseup" din't come to my rescue. I tried to use "touchend" and "gesturemoveend" events as suggested by YUI3 documentation, but in both cases onSubmit() wicket java code is executed before the javascript.

Then, I tried to invoke javascript as below:

```
onSubmit(target, form)
{
target.appendJavaScript("new submitBehavior_js('click',<<parameters>>)");
System.out.println("Inside Submit method in wicket");
String[] imgArray = null;
imgdata = hiddenImageData.getValue();
imgArray = imgData.split(',');    
.........
}
```

With above piece of code, control is going to java script from Wicket controller but comes back to java code before executing the onLoad() of Canvas element. Here is my java script snippet...myCanvas is an hidden element on HTML(style=display:none)

```
alert("Start here");
var imgArray[];
var lineCtr = 0;

for each LI List item (Say I have 2 items)
{
var imageObjectURL = node.get('children').getAttribute('href')
image = new Image()
image.onLoad = function() {

alert("Inside onload of image to canvas");
var canvas = document.getElementById("#myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRectangle('white');
ctx.drawImage(image,700,600,0,0);
var data  = ctx.toDataUrl();

imgArray[lineCtr] = data;
Y.one("#hiddenImageData").setAttribute('value',imgArray);
lineCtr = lineCtr + 1;
alert("finished here");

}

image.src = imageObjectURL;
alert("after assigning object URL. Completed List item");
}
```

The order of display/alert is as follows:

```
alert - Start here 
alert - after assigning object URL. Completed List item 
alert - after assigning object URL. Completed List item 
JAVA Sysout  - Inside Submit method in wicket 
alert - Inside onload of image to canvas 
alert - finished here 
alert - Inside onload of image to canvas 
alert - finished here
```

Because on load of Canvas element is executed after the java code, obviously the hidden Image Data variable has null values....and I am losing the captured/uploaded images by User.
Any reason for this weird behavior? or May be my understanding is wrong? Also, a better way to accomplish my task. 
Appreciate your time and help!!

Answer (score 0):

Do your JavaScript you want to do in an `IAjaxCallListener` like i showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870214/534877). This way you make sure it is executed before the `onSubmit()` login is executed.

Comment: Thanks Rober Niestroj. Per your answer link, I couldn't use IAjaxCallListener as we are using wicket 1.4.8. But, I was able to make use of getAjaxCallDecorator. However, the result is same. Though java script is executed first, Canvas element onLoad is happening after onSubmit() method of the Button. Not exactly sure how to overcome this.

Comment: Well, as per my understanding the problem is java script is executed binding the image to load event. As soon as the binding is completed, java script is finished and control comes back to Wicket. After that image load is completed and code inside onLoad is executed. Is there any way, I can wait till load event is triggered and complete processing inside onLoad() and then return to wicket controller.?